# Performance drop when including code exported from other Rcpp package

Tags: r, rcpp

I have recently created a package and would like to recycle many of the "under-the-hood" functions I wrote for it in a new package. However, in a first try I have found that there's a significant performance decrease when importing cpp code into the new package. I will clarify below.

I have *package1*, created via `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`. The package's only source file is *package1/src/shared.cpp*, which includes a function that calculates column sums of a matrix using RcppArmadillo. The source code for `shared.cpp` is thus:

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
//[[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]

#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec col_sums(const arma::mat& matty){
  return arma::sum(matty, 0).t();
}
```

Now suppose I want to recycle this function in another package, called *package2*. I do so by editing *Imports* and *LinkingTo* in DESCRIPTION, adding  *package1*. Then, the only source file for this new package is *package2/src/testimport.cpp*

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, package1)]]

#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
#include "package1.h"

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec col_sums(const arma::mat& test){
  return arma::sum(test,0).t();
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec col_sums_imported(const arma::mat& test){
  return package1::col_sums(test);
}
```

Now if I compile both packages, and benchmark the 3+1 functions, I get

```
library(magrittr)
library(rbenchmark)

nr <- 100
p <- 800

testmat <- rnorm(nr * p) %>% matrix(ncol=p)

benchmark(package2::col_sums(testmat),
          package2::col_sums_imported(testmat), 
          colSums(testmat),
          package1::col_sums(testmat),
          replications=1000)
```

I would expect there to be no difference at all between `package1::col_sums` and `package2::col_sums`, but also a minimal or small difference between those two and `package2::col_sums_imported`, which  calls `package1::col_sums` from `package2` using the cpp interface.

Instead I get (I also added R's colSums for a comparison)

```
                                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3                     colSums(testmat)         1000   0.050    1.429     0.052    0.000          0         0
4          package1::col_sums(testmat)         1000   0.035    1.000     0.036    0.000          0         0
1        package2::col_sums(testmat)         1000   0.038    1.086     0.036    0.000          0         0
2 package2::col_sums_imported(testmat)         1000   0.214    6.114     0.100    0.108          0         0
```

This **6x** slow-down puzzles me, because I was not expecting there to be such a difference. Is it preferrable to just copy the source of the "shared" functions to the new package, and why? I feel like having only one source for `col_sums` would allow me to more easily propagate changes across both packages. Or is there another reason why my code slows down so much?

**EDIT:** in addition to @duckmayr's answer below, I have updated my minimal github package example to show how a user-created function can be used in `package1`, exported to other packages, imported to `package2`. Code can be found at https://github.com/mkln/rcppeztest

Comment: Please construct a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This still has too many extra things flying around, is not complete and hence not verifiable.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I'm not sure how to write a more complete example than this, given that it requires the creation of at least 1 package. All the source code I'm using is in the question, no more no less. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Added everything to github for seamless installing and testing, hopefully. https://github.com/mkln/rcppeztest/

Comment: I've never played with `Rcpp::interfaces`, but usually, when you want Rcpp code of package1 to be available for other packages, you put this code in `inst/include/package1/`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @F.Privé I've only just now read your comment. sorry! Anyway yes indeed, unfortunately I only found clear instructions on how to use `Rcpp::interfaces` and was afterwards puzzled by what was going on. Everything is clearer now though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others, allowing other packages to call your C++ code from C++ requires the use of header files in `inst/include/`. `Rcpp::interfaces` allows you to automate the creation of such files. However, as I demonstrate below, creating your own headers manually can result in faster execution time. I believe it is because relying on `Rcpp::interfaces` to create your headers for you may result in more complicated header code.

Before I go further and demonstrate a "simpler" approach that results in faster execution time, I need to note that while this works for me (and I have used the approach I will demonstrate below several times without issue), the more "complex" approach taken by `Rcpp::interfaces` is used in part to comport with statements in [Section 5.4.3. of the Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages). (Specifically, the bits having to do with `R_GetCCallable` you'll see below). So, improve your execution time with the code I offer below at your own peril.<sup>1,2</sup>

A simple header to share the code for `col_sums` might look like this:

```
#ifndef RCPP_package3
#define RCPP_package3

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

namespace package3 {
    inline arma::vec col_sums(const arma::mat& test){
      return arma::sum(test,0).t();
    }
}

#endif
```

However, the header created by `Rcpp::interfaces` looks like this:

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#ifndef RCPP_package1_RCPPEXPORTS_H_GEN_
#define RCPP_package1_RCPPEXPORTS_H_GEN_

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace package1 {

    using namespace Rcpp;

    namespace {
        void validateSignature(const char* sig) {
            Rcpp::Function require = Rcpp::Environment::base_env()["require"];
            require("package1", Rcpp::Named("quietly") = true);
            typedef int(*Ptr_validate)(const char*);
            static Ptr_validate p_validate = (Ptr_validate)
                R_GetCCallable("package1", "_package1_RcppExport_validate");
            if (!p_validate(sig)) {
                throw Rcpp::function_not_exported(
                    "C++ function with signature '" + std::string(sig) + "' not found in package1");
            }
        }
    }

    inline arma::vec col_sums(const arma::mat& matty) {
        typedef SEXP(*Ptr_col_sums)(SEXP);
        static Ptr_col_sums p_col_sums = NULL;
        if (p_col_sums == NULL) {
            validateSignature("arma::vec(*col_sums)(const arma::mat&)");
            p_col_sums = (Ptr_col_sums)R_GetCCallable("package1", "_package1_col_sums");
        }
        RObject rcpp_result_gen;
        {
            RNGScope RCPP_rngScope_gen;
            rcpp_result_gen = p_col_sums(Shield<SEXP>(Rcpp::wrap(matty)));
        }
        if (rcpp_result_gen.inherits("interrupted-error"))
            throw Rcpp::internal::InterruptedException();
        if (Rcpp::internal::isLongjumpSentinel(rcpp_result_gen))
            throw Rcpp::LongjumpException(rcpp_result_gen);
        if (rcpp_result_gen.inherits("try-error"))
            throw Rcpp::exception(Rcpp::as<std::string>(rcpp_result_gen).c_str());
        return Rcpp::as<arma::vec >(rcpp_result_gen);
    }

}

#endif // RCPP_package1_RCPPEXPORTS_H_GEN_
```

So, I created two additional packages via

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "package3", example_code = FALSE)
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "package4", example_code = FALSE)
```

Then in `package3/inst/include`, I added `package3.h` containing the "simple header" code above (I also added a throwaway "Hello World" cpp file in `src/`). In `package4/src/` I added the following:

```
#include <package3.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec col_sums(const arma::mat& test){
  return arma::sum(test,0).t();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec simple_header_import(const arma::mat& test){
  return package3::col_sums(test);
}
```

as well as adding `package3` to `LinkingTo` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Then, after installing the new packages, I benchmarked all the functions against each other:

```
library(rbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
nr <- 100
p <- 800
testmat <- matrix(rnorm(nr * p), ncol = p)

benchmark(original = package1::col_sums(testmat),
          first_copy = package2::col_sums(testmat),
          complicated_import = package2::col_sums_imported(testmat),
          second_copy = package4::col_sums(testmat),
          simple_import = package4::simple_header_import(testmat),
          replications = 1e3,
          columns = c("test", "relative", "elapsed", "user.self", "sys.self"),
          order = "relative")


                test relative elapsed user.self sys.self
2         first_copy    1.000   0.174     0.174    0.000
4        second_copy    1.000   0.174     0.173    0.000
5      simple_import    1.000   0.174     0.174    0.000
1           original    1.126   0.196     0.197    0.000
3 complicated_import    6.690   1.164     0.544    0.613
```

While the more "complicated" header function was 6x slower, the "simpler" one was not.

---

<sub>1. However, the automated code generated by `Rcpp::interfaces` does in fact include some features that may be superfluous for you beside the `R_GetCCallable` issue, though they may be desirable and in some other contexts necessary.</sub>

<sub>2. Registering functions is always portable, and package authors are instructed to do so by the Writing R Extensions manual, but for internal/organizational/etc. use I believe the approach featured here should work if all packages involved are built from source. See [this section of Hadley Wickham's R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#c-export) for some discussion as well as the section of the Writing R Extensions manual linked above.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I think this explains it. I initially thought the problem would be alleviated by using `//[[Rcpp::interfaces(cpp)]]`  (i.e. removing `r` as an interface), but I didn't see any difference in the header file after doing this, hence the only effect seemed to be that R didn't see the exported function. 
I see you defined the function inline. What if I already have headers and .cpp in `/src/` for the same function? How can I add a header to `inst/include` for those functions? This would save some time and I guess this is what `Rcpp::interfaces` is meant for

Comment: @mkln You'll notice in the auto-generated header it's also defined `inline`. The reason we do this in header files is to avoid issues with the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). In terms of headers in `src/` or `/inst/include/` (or both), I would follow the rule of thumb that you put headers in `src/` if only your package will ever need them and in `inst/include/` if you want to allow other packages to potentially use them.

Comment: That makes sense. So what happens if I have headers with declarations of functions that I want to export and a separate `.cpp` file with the definitions? Can I move the headers to `/inst/include`, adding the namespace, and use `#include ../inst/include/newheader.h` in the .cpp file in `src/`?

Comment: Two comments: (1) as a colleague told me, it may have to do with the conversion to/from Armadillo, which I guess makes a copy of the data? I think this might be responsible for part of the performance decrease. (2) if I declare the `package1::col_sums` function in `inst/include/package1.h` and define it in `src/package1functions.cpp` then I can use it in `package1` but I cannot get a successful build of `package2`. Instead if I define it inline, `package2` compiles correctly and everything works. But is there a way to avoid defining all exported functions inline in `inst/include/package1.h`?

Comment: @mkln (1) I don't think conversions to/from Armadillo explain the difference, since all the functions would be hit by that performance penalty; (2) (and also related to comment before numbered questions) While headers are often used within package to declare functions that are defined elsewhere, if you're providing definitions to be used by other packages, the definition needs to be in the header files (and this only works when the package linking to you compiles from source) or registered as in `Rcpp::interfaces` (the way recommended by Writing R Extensions and the most portable)

Comment: (1) I'm not sure about what impact conversion `Rcpp::wrap(matty)` & `Rcpp::as<arma::vec >(rcpp_result_gen)` might have, but it would only affect the imported function and not the others. a pass by value in armadillo on the same data makes the function 2x slower though. Anyway thanks for (2) I guess I'll have some reordering to do. I'm marking your answer as the solution. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Three things come to my mind:

1. Does `rbenchmark` do a "warm up" cycle? If not, then the first invocation of `package1::col_sums` is paying the price of [calling an R function](https://github.com/mkln/rcppeztest/blob/9ed7b34c9df76ada1310911e81ff2bfc788796c2/package1/inst/include/package1_RcppExports.h#L17). That might account for the 0.1s of system time.
2. The function returns an Armadillo object. But when called via R, this has to be converted to an R object and [back](https://github.com/mkln/rcppeztest/blob/9ed7b34c9df76ada1310911e81ff2bfc788796c2/package1/inst/include/package1_RcppExports.h#L46). I am not sure how light-weight these conversions are, or if data copies are made in (some) cases.
3. The function might be to simple. Execution time is about 36 µs per function call. It seems plausible that doing this via R adds some significant overhead.

Overall, if you want to share such short running functions, you should convert them into "header only" and place them in `inst/include/`, as suggested by [F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103040/f-priv%C3%A9) in the comments. However, you will only share the source code but not the object code this way, i.e. `package2` will have to be recompiled when the function in `package1` changes.

I was curious to see how efficient it is to call a function exported via R. I therefore added a simple test function to a sample package:

```
//[[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int mysleep(int msec) {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::microseconds(msec));
  return msec;
}
```

I then compared calling this function either directly or indirectly as exported function for sleep times 50, 500 and 5000 µs. The median execution times as reported by `bench::mark`:

```
            50µs  500µs     5ms   mem_alloc
direct     153µs  688µs  5.37ms      2.47KB 
indirect   163µs  705µs  5.39ms      4.95KB
```

To me this looks as if calling such a simple function indirectly adds only a few 10µs of overhead on this rather slow machine. However, we already see that the amount of memory allocated is doubled. If we look at your function that returns a more complicated structure, we get:

```
  expression   min  mean median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
  <chr>      <bch> <bch> <bch:> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
1 direct     141µs 148µs  145µs 830.14µs     6737.    10.4KB     0  3342
2 imported   344µs 703µs  832µs   1.17ms     1423.   644.2KB     7   628
```

The amount of memory allocated in the indirect call is more than 60 times greater! To me this explains the performance drop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions! As for your three points, (1) I tried multiple times but I've seen no change from 4/6x. (2) all the 3+1 functions only go to R as the very last step. the only difference is that `package2::col_sums_imported` calls a function from `package1` (without going through R and using references). (3) I agree that the simple function might make the numbers worse, but still, all of the functions only go to R at the end.
Finally, I think the point of `Rcpp::interfaces` is to add a header to `inst/include/` precisely, taking care of this step automatically. Again, thanks!

Comment: @mkln I still think that the conversions mentioned in (2) are relevant. If ou use `bench::mark` on your functions you will see that there is quite a lot of memory allocation happening in the imported function.